# Laravel/Eloquent - Creating relationship of multiple child models related to a parent model that may or may not have an attribute

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm a beginer and non english speaker, so I apologies on advance.

I guess this should be answered with Accessors or some kind of  Polymorphic Relationships. But im understanding it well, so looking for a simple expample to understand it better. Or maybe this could be achived with another method?

Having a parent reference model:

- id
- reference_name

and multiple childs models related:

- id
- width
- long
- weight *(this field may or may not exists / writed as INT)*
- thickness *(this field may or may not exists / writed as INT)*
- *other specific fields for each model*

Some of the child only have thckness, other just weight and some may have both. I can't create only one table and leave it nullable. There must be multiple tables for each subcategory, so I have to had multiples models.

one child can would be:

**Subcategory1**

- id
- width
- long
- weight

**Subcategory2**

- id
- width
- long
- thickness

**Subcategory3**

- id
- width
- long
- weight
- thickness

Is there anyway I can create a relationship and access attributes from parent reference like this:

```
$reference->thickness;
```

This should retrieve witdth if it exists and null if doesn't.

Comment: why do you wanna use multiple models for each subcategory?

Comment: In the end those subcatgory products prices should be calculated by absolutly differents parmeters. So I decided to split each one in different subcategories with their owns attributes. But some of them may or may not share somes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution. It was a simple One To One (Polymorphic) relationship.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one-polymorphic-relations

---OLD---

I did a ugly work around with something like this. Still waiting if someone could know the elegant way to make this work

```
class Reference extends Model {

....

public function getCustom($searchedAttribute)
{
    $group = $this->group;

    if(!$group){
        return Null;
    }

    $reference_id= $this->id;

    switch($group->name){
        case 'subcategory1':
            $reference = Subcategory1::where('reference_id','=',$reference_id)->first();
            if(isset($reference->$searchedAttribute)){
                return $reference->$searchedAttribute;
            }else{
                return Null;
            }
            break;

        case 'subcategory2':
            $reference = Subcategory2::where('reference_id','=',$reference_id)->first();
            if(isset($reference->$searchedAttribute)){
                return $reference->$searchedAttribute;
            }else{
                return Null;
            }
            break;  
         
        case n:
            ...
            break;
        

        default:
            return Null;
            break;
    }


}
```